# BizTalk "New" SharePoint Adapter Send Document Silent Fail

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have a BizTalk 2016 solution. It's collecting a document (Pdf or Word) from a varbinary(max) column of a Sql Server database, along with some metadata. So, the message that makes its way to the messagebox from the Sql Receive Port looks like:

```
<TypedPolling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/ReadyForBizTalk">
<TypedPollingResultSet0>
    <TypedPollingResultSet0>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <DocId>104</DocId>
        <Uprn>76675</Uprn>
        <Address1>48 Cardinal Square </Address1>
        <Address2>City</Address2>
        <Address3>County</Address3>
        <Postcode>AF1 5FF</Postcode>
        <Title>Doc title</Title>
        <DocType>Pdf</DocType>
        <Version>-1</Version>
        <Date>30/01/2019 14:46:26</Date>
        <Description>Description</Description>
        <FilePath />
        <Extension>.pdf</Extension>
        <SystemGenerated>false</SystemGenerated>
        <Content>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...</Content>
        <ProcessedByBizTalk>false</ProcessedByBizTalk>
    </TypedPollingResultSet0>
</TypedPollingResultSet0>
```

I want BizTalk to send this to send the binary document (content of the Content element) and the metadata "Title" value to a SharePoint 2013 document library. I have created a send port and configured the following properties:

- Use Cleint OM = Yes
- Destination Folder URL
- SharePoint Site URL
- Column 01 = Title
- Column 01 Value = %XPATH=//Title%

I realise that I've not made any attempt to send the "Content" yet but I thought I'd try to get this simple case working first.

When I set a new rec to be collected from the Sql Server table, it is collected ok by BizTalk and I can see from Tracked Messages that a send is made through the SharePoint adaptor. There are no errors either in the BizTalk admin console or event log, but new item appears in the document library

I have a couple of questions:

1. Any ideas why nothing new is appearing on the doc library?
2. Once I'm able to persist "something" to SharePoint library, does anyone know how I can get the binary document into the library?